# Problems with Rattle and RGtk2 installation

Tags: rattle, rgtk2

I have followed the instructions at https://rattle.togaware.com/ for installing R4.1.3 and RGtk2. Here are the issues I am facing:

(1) When I try to load RGtk2 with the command ">library(RGtk2)", I get this message:
Error: package ‘RGtk2’ was built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

(2) When I try to load Rattle with the command ">Rattle()", it asks me to install GTk+, and goes into an endless loop.

I was expecting a smooth transition to the Rattle interface (especially as that is what I got when installing R4.1.2 and Rattle last year).

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks.